# Facebook 'View Content' Pixel Event parameter not matching data feed

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a Google feed that I am using for Facebook retargeting. Everything seems to be working fine in terms of the account set up and ad approval, but it is failing to match the products viewed to the products in the feed. Here is what I have -

How product appears in Feed

```
<g:id>TCY1021 000-571-2XL</g:id>
<g:item_group_id>TCY1021 000-571</g:item_group_id>
<title><![CDATA[Tog24 Mens Prime Down Jacket Blue]]></title>
<link>http://www.xxxxxxxxx.co.uk/mens-prime-down-jacket-blue/</link>
<g:price>140.00GBP</g:price>
<g:sale_price>98.00GBP</g:sale_price>
```

and here is what is being reported in Facebook in the error log -

```
{"content_type":"product","content_ids":"[\"TCY1021 000-571\"]","value":"98","currency"
:"GBP","content_name":"Prime Down Jacket"}
```

Are these backslashes what is causing the product to not match with the datafeed?

If not do you know what is?

Here is what the pixel helper returns -

[image]

and here is the source code for the event -

```
<!-- Begin Facebook ViewContent Pixel -->
<script type="text/javascript">
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {"content_type":"product",
"content_ids":["TCY1021000-571"],"value":98,"currency":"GBP","content_name":"Prime Down 
Jacket"});

</script>
<!-- End Facebook ViewContent Pixel -->
```

Comment: How can Facebook report `TCY1021 000-571` in the error log, when you are sending `TCY1021000-571` …?

Comment: I really don't know! I can't work it out.